# English translation of the Navagraha Kavacham?

Tags: translation-request, navagraha

I would like to have an English translation of the meaning of the [Navagraha Kavacham](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_navagraha/navagrahakavacham.html?lang=iast).
Does someone know if there is an English translation and where I can find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am trying to translate it on my own:

> ब्रह्मोवाच ।  शिरो मे पातु मार्ताण्डो कपालं रोहिणीपतिः ।
> मुखमङ्गारकः पातु कण्ठश्च शशिनन्दनः ।
>
> Lord BrahmA said:
>
> Let the head be protected by MArtanda (Sun) and the forehead by
> Rohinipati (referring to Moon who is the husband of Rohini). Let the face (Mukham) be  protected by
> AngArakah (or Mars) and the throat (Kantham) by Sashinandanah (or the
> son of Sasi or Moon-referring to Budha).
>
> बुद्धिं जीवः सदा पातु हृदयं भृगुनन्दनः ।
>  जठरञ्च शनिः पातु जिह्वां
> मे दितिनन्दनः ॥
>
> Let the intellect (Buddhi) be protected by Jivah (or Brihaspati) and the heart (Hridayam) by Bhrigunandanah (son of
> Bhrigu- referring to Shukra). Let the belly be protected by Shani and
> the tongue by Ditinandanah (referring to RAhu)
>
> पादौ केतुः सदा पातु वाराः सर्वाङ्गमेव च ।
>  तिथयोऽष्टौ दिशः पान्तु
> नक्षत्राणि वपुः सदा ॥
>
> Let the feet always be protected by Ketu and all-body by VArAh (Week Days). Let
> the Tithis protect all the 8 directions (ashta disha) and the Nakshtras protect my body always.
>
> अंसौ राशिः सदा पातु योगाश्च स्थैर्यमेव च ।
>  गुह्यं लिङ्गं सदा
> पान्तु सर्वे ग्रहाः शुभप्रदाः ।
>
> Let the two Aṃsa (Shoulders) be protected by Rashis(zodiac signs)
> and the Yogas (astrological Yogas - Dhriti, Shiva, Siddhi, Vaidhriti, Preeti et cetera 27 Yogas) protect my stability. Let the anus and genital be protected by
> all the Grahas who are the giver of auspiciousness.

Now, the translation for the Phalashruti part:

> aṇimādīni sarvāṇi labhate yaḥ paṭhed dhruvam ॥
>
> One who readsthis is bound to get the AnimAdi (AnimA, LaghimA etc) 8 Siddhis.
>
> etāṃ rakṣāṃ paṭhed yastu bhaktyā sa prayataḥ sudhīḥ ।
>  sa cirāyuḥ
> sukhī putrī raṇe ca vijayī bhavet ॥
>
> The wise one who reads this Protection Stotra with devotion always, gets long-life, happiness,
> progeny, and victory in battles.
>
> aputro labhate putraṃ dhanārthī dhanamāpnuyāt ।
>  dārārthī labhate
> bhāryāṃ surūpāṃ sumanoharām ।
>
> The son-less one gets sons, the one desirous of wealth gets wealth.
> The one who desires wife gets a beautiful wife charming to mind.
>
> rogī rogātpramucyeta baddho mucyeta bandhanāt ।
>  jale sthale
> cāntarikṣe kārāgāre viśeṣataḥ ।
>
> [By reading it] the diseased ones get rid of their diseases. The one
> who is in bondage, be it in water, earth or in the sky and specially in prisons, gets rid of
> the bondage.
>
> yaḥ kare dhārayennityaṃ bhayaṃ tasya na vidyate ।
>  brahmahatyā
> surāpānaṃ steyaṃ gurvaṅganāgamaḥ ।
>  sarvapāpaiḥ pramucyeta
> kavacasya ca dhāraṇāt ॥
>
> One who wears it in arms (kare), does not know what fear is. And also all the
> sins like Brahmincide, drinking liquor, theft, cohabiting with Guru's
> wife etc are destroyed upon wearing the Kavacha (kavacasya ca dhāraṇāt).
>
> nārī vāmabhuje dhṛtvā sukhaiśvaryasamanvitā ।
>  kākavandhyā
> janmavandhyā mṛtavatsā ca yā bhavet ।
>  bahvapatyā jīvavatsā
> kavacasya prasādataḥ ॥
>
> The woman who wears the Kavacha on her left arm (VAma bhuje dhritvA) becomes endowed with all kinds of happiness and wealth (Aiswarya).
>
> Be she a woman who is unable to produce a second child(Kaakavandhyaa), or be a woman who cannot produce child at all (Janmavandhyaa), or be she whose children are born dead (mritavatsaa),
> by the blessing of this Kavacha that woman becomes endowed with many children who are born alive.
>
> iti grahayāmale uttarakhaṇḍe navagraha kavacaṃ samāptam ||
>
> Here ends the Navagraha Kavacham, which is found in Graha YAmala's
> Uttara Khanda

This Kavacha (or armour) is found in one of the Tantric texts called Graha YAmala.

Comment: Wow @Rickross such nice and precise translation. And you are right that Jeeva is Brihaspati (I have read many times him as Jeeva) and also you are right that Diti Nandana refers to Raahu (because Ketu then comes in second line, and usually Rahu is mentioned first). Such nice translation. 

Comment: @AnuragSingh Thank you. Initially i  was not sure about Jivah, but later remember reading about it being one name for Brihaspati (probably read that in Brihaspati Stotra or Kavacha).. so added that in one edit.

Comment: Nice addition on "yogashcha sthairmeva cha"..i could not get that it's the Yoga from the Panchangas that is being talked about..@AnuragSingh

Comment: Yes, since it is a Navagraha kavacham i expected that only the Grahas will be requested to protect the different parts of the devotee's body..this is what happens in Kaavcha..but they also asking some of the Panchangas to do so.. also i knew the meaning of Kakavandhya, Janmavandhya etc as they are also Bengali words.. but i just translated Vandya as barren.. @AnuragSingh

Comment: Haha.  Yes, after all Panchangs depend on Grahas also. And it's no problem adding meaning of Kaakavandhyaa, Janmavandhyaa. I too was thinking how come Rickross not write translation for those verses Kaakavandhyaa, Janmavandhyaa.......